# How to get Twilio Recording file in PHP

Tags: php, twilio

I am using Twilio application. I want to get the path of my recording. I am using this code:

```
$client = new Services_Twilio($sid, $token, $version);

$calls = $client->account->calls->getIterator(0, 50, array(      
)); 

$url = $call->subresource_uris->recordings;
```

in the variable `$url` `/2010-04-01/Accounts/<acount id>/Calls/callerid/Recordings.json`

But when i paste this url `"https://api.twilio.com/2010-04-01/Accounts/<acount id>/Calls/callerid/Recordings.json"` it gives me alert popup to enter user name and password.

Basically i want this file to save on my system

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Twilio evangelist here.

The URL you are using is requesting a list of [Recording](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/recording) *resources* from Twililo, not the actual audio files.  Each resource contains a property called *[Url](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/recording#instance-properties)* that represents that actual audio recording file.

If you want to download the audio, you will need to loop through that list of recordings and make a [new HTTP GET request](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/recording#instance-get) to the Url specified in the Url property.

Hope that helps.

Comment: can also try the API Explorer